# How to avoid 'double' event double binding?

Tags: jquery, yii, cgridview, cjuidialog

I've got a page containing numerous links that will trigger a cjuidialog to open:

```
<?php foreach($client->assignments as $clientProjects) { ?>
    [...]
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"
        id="attach_file_project_<?=$clientProjects['project_id']?>"
        class="attach_timesheet_file"
        data-id="<?=$clientProjects['project_id']?>"
        data-week-start="<?=$client->clientWeek[0]?>"
        data-week-end="<?=$client->clientWeek[6]?>"
    >Attach File</a>
    [...]
<?php } ?>
```

This is the script that will trigger the dialog. The dialog content is being generated in the ajax call:

```
$(".attach_timesheet_file").off('click').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#files-grid .delete').off('click');
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var weekStart = $(this).data("week-start");
    var weekEnd = $(this).data("week-end");
    var url = "<?=Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/timesheetNew/attachTimesheet')?>";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:url + "?id=" + id + "&week_start=" + weekStart + "&week_end=" + weekEnd,
        success: function(data) {
            var modal = $("#attachFileModal");
            modal.html(data);
            modal.dialog('open');
            return true;
        }
    })
});
```

The dialog allows you to add & delete files.
Inside the dialog, I'm using a CGridView widget which will include a delete link:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', [
    'id' => 'files-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [...]
        [
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{delete}',
            'buttons' => [
                'delete' => [
                    'label' => 'Delete',
                    'imageUrl' => null,
                    'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("admin/timesheetNew/deleteFile", ["id" => $data["id"]])'
                ]
            ],
            'deleteConfirmation' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this file?',
            'afterDelete' => 'function(){
                $("#files-grid").yiiGridView("update");
            }'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

The problem I'm facing is when I open, close and re-open a dialog, and I wish to delete a file, I need to click the confirm button as many times as I opened a dialog.

I tried with $(".attach_timesheet_file").off('click'), which should work to unbind the event, but it didn't help, also trying the same for #files-grid .delete didn't work as well.

Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: btw, double binding for the delete button is already fixed, that was done by adding:
 $('#files-grid .delete').off('click');

This fixed the issue of having the same problem with event binding while being inside the same dialog and having to click confirm more and more depending on how many files you added/deleted

Answer (score 0):

My approach is "tag" the new binding with a unique class.
I already think about using some dataset property but adding a unique class looks easier to use.
By the way, the problem about use "off('click')" is that you unbind any other click that you already have;

```
$('#filtro').not('.bindfiltro').change(function () {
    $(this).submit();
}).addClass('bindfiltro');
```